# Which Chrome directories can be safely removed to clean up the storage?

Tags: google-chrome, storage, chromium, disk-cleanup

Which Chrome directories can be safely removed to clean up the storage?

In particular, what do `shared_proto_db` and `File System` do?

[image]
[image]

Comment: What are you willing to lose? Bookmarks are 10MB. Your history is 23MB.

Comment: This is probably another X-Y problem or is there a good reason for you to want to do that?

Answer (score 1):

The entire `/Default` folder is safe to delete as far as Chrome is concerned. It contains only user data (settings, bookmarks, history, passwords, sessions, extensions, etc) which you'll lose. Chrome will create a new folder on next start.

---

A less destructive method is navigating to **Chrome > Settings > Reset settings**, which will keep some things like passwords and bookmarks, but clears most cached garbage.

Comment: I don't want to lose my extensions or their settings. I only want to delete caches and local storage of websites.

Comment: Then go into Chrome settings and search for "Cache" and you will (most likely) see where to go and what options there are.

Comment: @HappyFace Like Hannu says, you can delete cached images and files from chrome settings under `chrome://settings/clearBrowserData`. Some extensions may mark their files as a different type, but should still show up in that wizard